# What kind of scripture is the Naradiyakalpam?

Tags: scripture, sri-vaishnava, agamas, pancharatra, vedanta-desika

What kind of scripture is the *Naradiyakalpam*?

Medieval Sri Vaishnava scholar [Vedanta Desika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta_Desika) cites this scripture in support of the view that the [pranava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) in the secret Ashtakshara mantra important in Sri Vaishnavism cannot be chanted by women and shudras, but instead should be replaced with an equivalent variant.

Is the Naradiyakalpam a [Pancharatra Agama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra), or is it referring to the [Naradiya Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naradiya_Purana), or is it referring to the shortened form of the Bhagavata Purana which has the name "Naradiyam"?